# Scifi Movie: Alien family comes to Earth and causes chaos

Tags: story-identification

I watched a scifi movie a long time ago (1980-1990?) and I can't for the life of me work out what it is.

- The movie was about an alien family (or only a mother and a child, don't remember) that came to Earth and caused all kinds of chaos.
- I think to remember that the mother was kind of a robot or cyborg or so, because she could transform her hand into tools, if I remember correctly...

**Scene 1 (not chronologically maybe):**
The alien child has a toy that looks like an elephant on two legs. This toy somehow grows and comes to life and causes trouble in a bar or restaurant or so... In this scene the elephant monster steps on a guys head, that transforms it, but he runs around with the deformed head later I think...

**Scene 2**
The mother alien puts here hands in a meat grinder and although it shreds the fingers, she is not impressed in any way and grows the fingers back...

p.s. it's not *Mac and Me*

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have an excellent start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us. Also, I removed your salutation. Because while nice, we like to leave such things for the comments rather than the questions.

Comment: Hi amflare, thanks for the welcoming, also I found that edit of my post a little strict, but hey, if it's the rules... :-D
Unfortunately these are the only two scenes I vaguely remember...
I basically know nothing else about this movie anymore...